# Read .csv file with streamreader in c#

Tags: c#, csv

First of all i'm very new with coding and at the beginner level in c#. I look at the questions but couldn't find proper answer for my question or didn't understand.

I have a .csv file and the lines in the files are like below. I get the longitude value by using `float longitude = float.Parse(read[1]);` But I also want to get the number "3" in the example of below. In my opinion i can get the value by using `float.Parse(read[12])`. This number is in the 12th index in the line. But i cannot reach that number by using `float.Parse(read[12])`. When i use `float.Parse(read[9])` i can get the 3. This code is not reading the missing values between commas. How can i read all the data incluiding missing values? Because the other lines are different and missing values are changing. Some of the line doesn't include date information, some of them doesn't include longitude information.

> 0000000,26.0000000,38.000000,30.01.2017,0,0,0,,,0,0,,3,,0,0,0,0

```
string[] read;
char[] seperators = { ',' };

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:/xxx.csv");

string data = sr.ReadLine();

while ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    read = data.Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    float longitude = float.Parse(read[1]);
    float latitude = float.Parse(read[2]);
}
```

Comment: _"This code is not reading the missing values between commas"_ - please read [ask] and [mcve] and **show** the relevant code.

Comment: add in how do you get your `read[]`

Comment: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Document path");
                string data = sr.ReadLine();

                while ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    read = data.Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    float longitude = float.Parse(read[1]);
                    float latitude = float.Parse(read[2]); }

Comment: sorry for the complicate answer. i cannot write the code properly for reading.

Comment: read = data.Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

You explicitly skip empty entries, which makes it difficult to count indices. Just leave out that optional parameter, then

    read = data.Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

will include the empty parts of your csv-input as well.
But make sure, you do not run into exceptions while trying to parse empty strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line

```
read = data.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Says:

> If there are two commas, one right after the other, ignore the entry

Hence, your input becomes:

> 0000000,26.0000000,38.000000,30.01.2017,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0

What you really want is this, which leaves empty values in the array

```
read = data.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is this line:

```
 read = data.Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You are telling it to remove the empty values. The missing ones you want.
Change it to

```
 read = data.Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned you must change `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `StringSplitOptions.None`.

However, since this is the default parameter you can simply use:

```
read = data.Split(seperators);
```